# Changing an item in drop down after 5 latest posts per taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, database, taxonomy, dropdown

For now, I am looking for suggestions on how can I do it.

To get the current taxonomy:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

To get the latest 5 items:

```
$query_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => "5"
);

$listedPosts = new WP_Query($query_args);

// the loop

if ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
        $listedPosts->the_post();
        if ( (int) $listedPosts->current_post => 5 ) {
          // change the drop down field item to "Visible" from Invisible
        } else {
          // stay as is
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: you only get 5 posts; as 'current_post' starts with 0 zero, it will only ever go to maximal 4...

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look to the blow code-

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => '5',
    'orderby'           => 'post_date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);

$listedPosts = new WP_Query($query_args);

// the loop
if ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $listedPosts->have_posts() ) {
        $listedPosts->the_post();
        if ( (int) $listedPosts->current_post == 5 ) { // You need to use '==' or '===' for comparison.
            // change the drop down field item to "Visible" from Invisible
        } else {
            // stay as is
        }
    }
}
```

And-

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

This above code will give you the term ID when you are at a `taxonomy.php` page or `archive.php` page. In `single.php` page for getting taxonomy terms you need to use the below code-

**For inside a loop-**

```
//Do something if a specific array value exists within a post
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy _name', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    echo $term_single->slug; //do something here
}
```

**For outside of the loop-**

```
//Do something if a specific array value exists within a post
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_features', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    echo $term_single->slug; //do something here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! Any suggestion on how to change the drop down item?